# AsyncStorage.getItem with state values

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I new to react native, I trying to set AsyncStorage.getItem  and AsyncStorage.setItem to save my state values,I setup the AsyncStorage.setItem in componentWillMount() function, in the first time my app is running I have state that my component use and he have some keys with specific values, if I setup the AsyncStorage.setItem to get the last item from my state, my component fails.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userAnswer: '', count: 0};
  }

 componentWillMount(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem("userAnswer").then((value) => {
    this.setState({userAnswer: value})}).done();
  AsyncStorage.getItem("count").then((value) => {
    this.setState({count: value})}).done();
  }

saveData(){
  AsyncStorage.setItem("userAnswer",this.state.userAnswer);
  AsyncStorage.setItem("count",this.state.count);
};
```

I need that in the fist time the app is running the state should be the same meaning the count should stay 0, in my error the count appear as null

every help really appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("count").then((value) => {
    this.setState({count: value || 0})}).done();
  }
```